# SQL Select Subqueries and Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have been trying to solve a question for literally 15 hours plus, I've come to the conclusion that I am out the depth but would love a understanding of how its done.

The problem I am facing is the first question, with most of my problems stemming from the Home Team and Away Team Scores and Name.

This is how far i've gotten with the query.

```
SELECT home.TeamName AS HomeTeamName, home.Score AS HomeScore
FROM MatchParticipant home
LEFT JOIN Match m ON home.MatchID = m.MatchID
WHERE Field = 'Home' AND m.MatchStatus = 'NotStarted'
),
AwayTable AS(
SELECT away.TeamName AS AwayTeamName, away.Score AS AwayScore
FROM MatchParticipant away
RIGHT JOIN Match m ON away.MatchID = m.MatchID
WHERE Field = 'Away' AND m.MatchStatus = 'NotStarted'
)
SELECT HomeTeamName,HomeScore, AwayTeamName, AwayScore, StartDate, b.MatchID, MatchStatus, t.TournamentName,a.MatchParticipantID
FROM HomeTable, AwayTable, MatchParticipant a
INNER JOIN Match b ON b.MatchID=a.MatchID INNER JOIN Tournament t ON t.TournamentID=b.TournamentID
WHERE b.TournamentID = 2 AND b.MatchStatus = 'NotStarted'
```

Again I know this is incorrect, but hopefully someone can show me where I've gone wrong

Comment: A few things. 1) posting images that have copyright you don't own without attribution is not a great thing. 2) You're missing a with clause as the beginning. 3) Do NOT mix explicit and implicit joins. 4) You can join to same table twice so you don't need subqueries e.g. `FROM match m INNER JOIN MatchParticipant mpAway ON ... INNER JOIN MatchParticipant mpHome ON ...`

Comment: You're over complicating it way much. All it requires is 4 joins. Just join tournament to match and then to MatchParticipant twice (one for home teams and one for away teams)

Comment: You want specifically subquery? This is possible with joining `MatchParticipant` table 2 times too

Comment: If it can be done without it being a subquery that is fine.

I'm currently attempting to do it with just inner joins as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question A: get all premier league games that have not started.

I'll explain my thinking and hopefully someone will pull me up on where my logic may be lacking.

```
SELECT T.TournamentName
FROM Tournament T
WHERE TournamentId = 2
```

Returns 'Premier League'

Next we find matches that haven't started yet.

```
SELECT M.StartDate, M.MatchId T.TournamentId, M.MatchStatus
FROM Tournament T
LEFT JOIN Match M ON T.TournamentID = M.TournamentId
WHERE T.TournamentId = 2 AND M.MatchStatus = 'Not Started'
```

From here we join the table that gives us the extra details

```
SELECT H.TeamName As [HomeTeamName], H.Score As [HomeTeamScore], A.TeamName As [AwayTeamName], A.TeamScore As [AwayTeamScore], M.StartDate, M.MatchId T.TournamentId, M.MatchStatus
FROM Tournament T
LEFT JOIN Match M ON T.TournamentID = M.TournamentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN MatchParticipant H ON M.MatchId = H.MatchId
LEFT OUTER JOIN MatchParticipant A ON M.MatchId = A.MatchId
WHERE T.TournamentId = 2 AND M.MatchStatus = 'Not Started' AND H.Field = 'Home' AND A.Field = 'Away'
```

So the first join was a left join as it only includes results from the first table if there is a match in the second table. Then next join is a left outer join as it will return results from our first table even if there isn't any data in the MatchParticipant table yet.

From here you would need to consider what the default values are for match scores. If it's '0' then great, however if the result is missing you should consider investigating a CASE statement that sits in the SELECT statement which you basically say 'if score is NULL then output 0, else sent out the current score'

I hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you for submitting a answer, I have gotten this far myself however I assume HomeTeamName, HomeScore would have a Where Field = 'Home' and similar for Away.

Thats where I get stuck on.

Comment: Ahh apologies, I'm on mobile and on the gin! Bare with me and I'll edit

Comment: haha, no worries, thank you for your help. I can see how others mentioned I am overthinking it.

Enjoy the rest of your evening :)

Comment: I've edited it for you mate. How were you breaking it down in your head? I'm a been a graduate a year in July and im still learning. It's honestly the problems that you encounter that help you learn. How were you breaking this question down in your head?

Comment: Well I thought I had to almost produce to separate tables for Home and Away. My thought process was basically the same as yours until the end, How you dealt with the two MatchParticipant tables is much better and cleaner. Thanks Again Dan